# Linux Question on Find

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, find

I have a parent folder with permission 777 and its child folders with 600 where I am not the owner. I don't see here the folder 'ghi' in my output while using?

**Command**

```
find /abc/ -type d -perm 777 2>dev/null
```

**Folder Structure**

```
/abc/def/ghi/f123.txt
/abc/xyz/tuv/f123.txt
```

Consider 'def' has 777 permission but 'ghi' has 600 permission

Comment: In your command you state that you only want to see directorios wiht permission 777, so if ghi has perms 600, you will not see it in the output.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the mode 600 on directory 'def', you do not have permission to traverse it (as non-root), so the find command will fail to to access the contents of 'def'. This is why 'ghi' will not appear in the output.